# Get value with jsoup from webpage

Tags: android, jsoup

I am new with Jsoup
Current i want to get value of option but i can not.
Here is source of html page:

```
<div class="entrypost"> 
                        Xem nhanh: 
            <select  onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">                  <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-1.html" selected="selected"> Kim chi và củ cải phần 1</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-2.html" >Kim chi và củ cải phần 2</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-3.html" >Kim chi và củ cải phần 3</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-4.html" >Kim chi và củ cải phần 4</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-5.html" >Kim chi và củ cải phần 5</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-6.html" >Kim chi và củ cải phần 6</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-7.html" >Kim chi và củ cải phần 7</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-8.html" >Kim chi và củ cải phần 8</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-9.html" >Kim chi và củ cải phần 9</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-10.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 10</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-11.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 11</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-12.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 12</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-13.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 13</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-14.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 14</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-15.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 15</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-16.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 16</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-17.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 17</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-18.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 18</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-19.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 19</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-20.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 20</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-21.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 21</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-22.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 22</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-23.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 23</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-24.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 24</option>
                                    <option value="http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-25.html" >Kim Chi và Củ Cải Phần 25</option>
```

Here is my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-1.html");
// get all link
Elements elements1 = doc.select("option[value]");
Elements elements2 = elements1.select("value");
System.out.println("DDDDDDD " +elements1.size());
```

please help me if you can
thanks a lot!

Comment: I want to get all VALUE of all tag OPTION, but i can not. Please helllllllllllllllllllllp me. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-1.html").get();
```

instead of

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("http://truyenhay.vn/kim-chi-va-cu-cai-phan-1.html");
```